# Spark slave worker cannot bind to Driver on master

Tags: apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

I've got a DSE cluster with 3 machines: 1, 2 and 3.

When I submit an application to the master, if I understood well, it happens like this:

- Master receives the application and allocates resources
- Driver starts to run into the allocated worker
- Driver runs Executors on the other nodes of the cluster to share the workload

So we've got in this cluster this configuration:

- 1 is Master, has worker 1
- 2 is slave, has worked 2
- 3 is slave, has worker 3

When Spark chooses worker 1 (master) for the driver, everything runs just fine. 
But when Spark decides to allocate worker 2 (slave) or worker 3 (slave) to the driver, it tries to bind the the ip of the master and fails every time:

```
INFO  16:20:45  Changing view acls to: cassandra
INFO  16:20:45  Changing modify acls to: cassandra
INFO  16:20:45  SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(cassandra); users with modify permissions: Set(cassandra)
INFO  16:20:45  Slf4jLogger started
ERROR 16:20:46  failed to bind to /10.1.1.1:0, shutting down Netty transport
WARN  16:20:46  Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
INFO  16:20:46  Slf4jLogger started
ERROR 16:20:46  failed to bind to /10.1.1.1:0, shutting down Netty transport
WARN  16:20:46  Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
```

The configuration of each node is quite simple:

```
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP="10.1.1.1" // or .2 or .3
export SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS="xx.xx.xx.xx"
export SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077
export SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=7080
export SPARK_DRIVER_HOST="10.1.1.1" // or .2 or .3
export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=1
export SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY="10G"
```

I tried to set a spark.driver.port in spark-defaults.conf but it had no effect.

Here is the submit call:

```
/usr/bin/dse spark-submit --properties-file production.conf --master spark://10.1.1.1:7077 --deploy-mode cluster --class "com.company.SignalIO" aggregation.jar 2015-6-1-00:00:00 2015-6-2-00:00:00 signal_table
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What does your spark submit call look like in cron?

Comment: Added the spark submit call!